# Proof $F$ is a free module on $X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $\{X_i:i\in I\}$ be a collection of mutually disjoint sets and for each $i \in I$ let $F_i$ be a free module on $X_i$ with $l_i: X_i\rightarrow F_i$. Let $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$ and $F=\sum_{i\in I}F_i$ with $\phi_i:F_i\rightarrow F$ canonical injection. Define $l:X\rightarrow F$ by $l(x)=\phi_i \circ l_i(x)$ for $x\in X_i$. Prove that $F$ is a free module on $X$.

Comment: "A module"....over **what**? I'm guessing some ring, right? Are the $\;l_i\;$ injections? Why do we care about all those functions for this question? Are you defining "free module" as a certain set of functions with some binary operation between them...and over some ring? I find the question pretty foggy...and maybe if you'd add your own work it'd be clearer.

Comment: @DonAntonio Modules are over some ring $R$. (possibly without indetity) $l_i$ are of course injections. My definition of free module: Given a set $X$, a $R$-module $M$ and a function $f:X\to M$, the pair $(M,f)$ is said to be a free module over $X$ if for all $R$-modules $A$ and for all functions $g:X\to A$ there is exactly one $R$-module homomorphism $g':M\to A$ such that $g=g'\circ f$. I'm sorry but it is also not clear for me, that is why I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

Here's an abstract nonsense approach. As the sets $X_i$ are mutually disjoint, the union $X = \bigcup X_i$ is the coproduct of the $X_i$ in the category of sets. Essentially by definition of a free object, the free functor $Free: Sets \longrightarrow R-Mod$ is left adjoint to the forgetful functor $Forget: R-Mod \longrightarrow Sets$. Indeed, the universal property immediately gives you such a natural bijection. It is known that left adjoint functors are cocontinuous (preserve colimits). Thus, $Free(X) = \bigoplus Free(X_i)$, and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

We assume the $F_i$ are free over a common ring R. Clearly $X$ is a generating set for $F$, we must show it is linearly independent. Suppose that 
$$\sum_{\substack{ij\\finite}}a_{ij}x_{ij}=0$$
for $a_{ij}\in R$ and $x_{ij}\in X_i$ distinct. Since $X_i$ are all disjoint it follows that $F_i\not\in\text{Span}(F_j)_{j\in I\backslash \{i\}},$ so $$\sum_{i\in I} F_i=\bigoplus_{i\in I}F_i.$$
It follows that for all $i$ we must have
$$\sum_{j}a_{ij}x_{ij}=0,$$
but then since $F_i$ is free with basis $X_i$ it follows that $a_{ij}=0$ for all $i,j.$ Then $X$ is a basis for $F$ over $R,$ hence $F$ is free.

Comment: Thank you for this proof, I will try to analyze it later. But it has to be made with using these functions. Is there any possibility to fix this proof?

Comment: The proof is correct as is. If we wanted to use these maps we would just write $\ell_i(x_{ij})$ or $\phi_i\ell_i(x_{ij})$ depending on context. Everything else would be the same, as the maps are all injective, and the canonical projections are scalar multiplicative. So really all we are doing by not using the maps explicitly is making our generating sets easier to write out. Write, if $\ell_i(x_{ij})$ is a generating set we can make it simpler to write by associating it with $x_{ij}$ and getting an isomorphic module.

Comment: I got lost in all those definitions, can you confirm what you using in this post? $\sum_{i\in I}F_i$ is a direct product of modules and $\oplus_{i\in I}F_i$ is a direct sum of modules? If yes, I can't undestand why they are equal, can you explain it once again to me?

Comment: The direct product would be $\prod F_i$. The term $\sum F_i$ is a sum, not a product. It consists of all finite sums of elements belonging to $\bigcup F_i.$ To show the sum is direct would require that for all $i$ we have $F_i\not\in\text{Span}(F_j)_{j\not=I}$.